# Why SerialVersionUID is static

Tags: java, serialization

I am reading on Serialization in java.Java said that static variables are not serialized with the object.serialVersionUID is a must in serialization process.When an object is serialized,the serialVersionUID is serialized along with the other contents. This is one exception to the general serialization rule that, “static fields are not serialized”

Can anybody tell me why it is static.it can be nonstatic ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because any of the object variables/members can be accessed once Object is successfully created. You can't access Object variables without creating it. Now back to question, during deserialization, Object needs to be created from the data. If there's no way to check whether object is deserializable, there's no way to get the Object members.

For the same reason, UID is made as static.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

serialVersionUID is static because it applies not to class instance but class itself. It is saved in ObjectOutputStream class descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be static because it is mandated by the JRE to have it so. Reasoning may be simple, it can be accessed in a static way, without actually creating an object of the class.

From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a
>   version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during
>   deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized
>   object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with
>   respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the
>   object that has a different serialVersionUID than that of the
>   corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an
>   InvalidClassException. A serializable class can declare its own
>   serialVersionUID explicitly by declaring a field named
>   "**serialVersionUID" that must be static,** final, and of type long:

Comment: it doesn't say why? I think the OP is curious to know why JRE mandates it to be static

Answer (score 0):

It is an exception that it gets serialized . I believe it is `static` because it is bound to the class , not any instance of the class . All instances of the class should adhere to the same `serialVersionUID`. Again making it static means the run-time can actually get hold of that ID without creating any object, whereas prerequisite of de-serializing an object will be to ascertain the ID. When an object is serialized , the class name, the state of the object (non-static member variables) and the `serialVersionUID` are persisted .

Answer (score 0):

First, you should understand what a `serialVersionUID` does.

From [`java.io.Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a
>   version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during
>   deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized
>   object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with
>   respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the
>   object that has a different serialVersionUID than that of the
>   corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an
>   InvalidClassException.

The `serialVersionUID` determines compatibility between different versions of a *class*. Since the property is bound to the class, it has to be made `static`.

Answer (score -1):

That serialVersionUID is a convention to verify that you have the same binary versions in both the serializer and deserializer and nothing is going to go wrong with outdated versions. Also, it could be the case where you have identical names for different kind of classes in the deserializer, so that serialVersionUID is like a sort od unique identifier.

That's why it must be static (so it is "bounded to the class, not to every instance) and "sent" along with the serialized data.

Comment: "It could be the case where you have identical names for different kind of classes": no it couldn't, and if it could, `serialVersionUID` wouldn't help. It is not a 'unique identifier' in any sense. For example, they can all have the same value, such as 1.